# Adding style attributes to image called from another style

Tags: html, css

This is to add a spinning/loading icon for images as they load.

The existing code I'm using calls up an animated .gif image as a background image "behind" an image thumbnail, so the loading icon is visible until the thumbnail loads on top. But I want to replace the .gif with a higher quality .png and add CSS to make it rotate. It's a much cleaner look, but I don't know how or if I can add CSS style to `background: url(img/loading.png)`

Here's the original HTML code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.png) no-repeat center center; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 25%; height:25%;">
```

I want to add [this CSS code](http://www.jasonkenison.com/2014/09/63/Death-of-the-loading-gif) to the .png to make it rotate:

```
.loading {
-webkit-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
-moz-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { 
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { 
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); 
    }
}
@keyframes spin { 100% {
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

What's the best way to combine these to make my background .png image rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the div with the background, you just need to add the loading class to it and with a separate class to add the other styles to it like the background url, width, height, position etc...

```css
.load-style {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  background: url(http://www.jasonkenison.com/uploads/blog/loading.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.loading {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading load-style"></div>
```

Comment: I added the CSS to my style sheet and called out the two loading classes to my HTML like you have shown and it works, but the loading icon is positioned at the top-left corner of the div, not in the center like it did when I used the original code and .gif. Any suggestions?

Comment: I fixed my issue by resizing the original .png file and replacing your .load-style attributes with the original ones from the inline style in my HTML. Thanks, you've been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the class which your animating to the HTML. In your CSS you have a class called "loading" but the HTML doesn't know what to animate. In your div before the style="" tag add class="loading" and it will work, other than that your CSS works.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I wasn't trying to add the rotation style to my entire div, just the image I called out in the div's background. Thanks for the effort!